# Time Series Plot Date to Observation

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I would like to plot the number of observations per date. This way I can find sudden peaks in the recordings of observations. My date looks like this. How can I achieve this?

```
"2016-02-19 UTC"
"2016-02-19 UTC"
"2016-02-19 UTC"
"2016-02-19 UTC"
"2016-02-20 UTC"
"2016-02-20 UTC"
"2016-02-20 UTC"
"2016-02-20 UTC"
"2016-02-20 UTC"
"2016-02-20 UTC"
"2016-02-21 UTC"
"2016-02-21 UTC"
"2016-02-22 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a table to count the number of observations and then plot using `barplot`.

```
barplot(table(ObservationDates))
```

[image: Barplot]

> Data

```
ObservationDates = c("2016-02-19 UTC", "2016-02-19 UTC",
  "2016-02-19 UTC", "2016-02-19 UTC", "2016-02-20 UTC",
  "2016-02-20 UTC", "2016-02-20 UTC", "2016-02-20 UTC",
  "2016-02-20 UTC", "2016-02-20 UTC", "2016-02-21 UTC",
  "2016-02-21 UTC", "2016-02-22 UTC")
```

Comment: looking for something like this plot(table(df$date))

Comment: This Works  TimeSeries <- as.data.frame(unlist(table(df$date)))
TimeSeries$Var1 <- as.Date(TimeSeries$Var1)

ggplot(TimeSeries, aes(Var1, Freq)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)